# Display image in fullscreen from command line in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, bash

I would like to display from the command line an image in full-screen. I tried to use xli with the following command :

```
xli -onroot -fullscreen logo.gif
```

But it does not display anything. And when I run the following command:

```
xli -fullscreen logo.gif
```

It does display the image in a window which is as big as the screen, but I would like to see the image only (like a wallpaper) Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I like feh: feh -F PictureYouLike.png

Answer (score 8):

Ubuntu by default comes with `Eye of Gnome` , with has `-f` or `--fullscreen` flag

Run the command as such `eog --fullscreen myImage.png` or `eog -f myImage.png`

Answer (score 3):

You could use pqiv, a simple image viewer inspired by qiv.

At first install it:

```
sudo apt-get install pqiv
```

To view an image in fullscreen mode:

```
pqiv --fullscreen PATHTO/image
```